# Autoselección de comboboxes en C#

Tags: c#, combobox, arcgis

Buenas, tengo un problema bastante curioso:

Para comenzar trabajo programando aplicaciones SIG para ArcGIS 10.x utilizando Visual C# 2012 o 2013. Utilizando diferentes herramientas y comandos lleno unos `ComboBox` en Windows Forms.

Esto puedo hacerlo desde distintas fuentes, ya sea un simple archivo de texto o tablas en diferentes bases de datos.

Con el llenado no existe inconveniente alguno pero pasa que al abrir el formulario todos los combos que lleno desde el botón o comando anterior ya sale seleccionados y esto me produce errores, ya que existen combos que al seleccionarlos llenan otros de acuerdo a la selección.

Código:

```
private void cboPoste_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ProjectManager.LlenaComboEstruc(cboEstructura, "Estructuras", "Descripcion", "Codigo", cboTension.SelectedValue.ToString());
        cboEstructura.Enabled = true;
    }
private void cboEstructura_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectManager.LlenaComboEstruc(cboAnRiendas, "Estructuras", "Descripcion",
            "Codigo", "AR");
        ProjectManager.LlenaComboEstruc(cboTierra, "Estructuras", "Descripcion",
            "Codigo", "TP");
        ProjectManager.LlenaComboEstruc(cboAcometidas, "Estructuras", "Descripcion",
            "Codigo", "AC");
        ProjectManager.LlenaComboEstruc(cboOtros, "Estructuras", "Descripcion",
            "Codigo", "OT");
        //habilitamos los combos
        cboAnRiendas.Enabled = true;
        cboTierra.Enabled = true;
        if (cboTension.SelectedValue.ToString() == "MT")
        {
            ProjectManager.LlenaComboEstruc(cboEstruc2, "Estructuras", "Descripcion",
           "Codigo", "BT");
            cboEstruc2.Enabled = true;
            ProjectManager.LlenaComboEstruc(cboCuchillas, "Estructuras", "Descripcion",
            "Codigo", "CU");
            cboCuchillas.Enabled = true;
        }
        cboAcometidas.Enabled = true;
        cboOtros.Enabled = true;
        cmdAceptar.Enabled = true;
    }
///Esta funcion esta en la clase ProjecManager:
public static void LlenaComboEstruc(ComboBox Combo, string tabla, string campo, string index, string categoria)
    {
        Combo.Items.Clear();
        string path = @"D:\DELBENI\Proyectos.gdb";
        DataTable pTable = new DataTable();
        if (categoria != "")
            LlenaDataTableEstruc(path, pTable, tabla, campo, index, categoria);
        else
            LlenaDataTable(path, pTable, tabla, campo, index);
        Combo.DataSource = pTable;
        Combo.ValueMember = index;
        Combo.DisplayMember = campo;
        Combo.Text = "(Seleccionar)";
    }
```

Como cargo el combo cboPoste desde un comando externo al form, ya me aparce el combo seleccionado (cboEstructura) con el primer item y así sucesivamente ya que al seleccionar la Estructura se cargan otros, obviamente la propiedad Modifiers de todos los combos esta seteada en 'Public'

Comment: Buenos días. Incluye el código donde realizas la carga para que podamos ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: Lo normal es que al cargar un `ComboBox`,elimines primero los que dependen de el y sitúes el `SelectedIndex` en -1. Pero sin ver tu código, es muy muy difícil ayudarte.Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para aprender a hacer una buena pregunta.

Comment: Agrego el codigo:

Comment: Gracias por los consejos, acabo de agregar el código

Answer (score 0):

Para que no salga ningun elemento elemento seleccionado puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
comboBox.ResetText();
```

//o tambien puedes hacer esto para reiniciar el valor seleccionado

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Estos los puedes llamar en el Load del form

Comment: Lo hice, y funciona, pero luego cuando hago la selección de otro combo me sale el error "No se puede modificar la colección Items cuando está establecida la propiedad DataSource" Eso me imagino porque estas lineas no evitan que se selccione el item al cargar el combo, o sea, selecciona y luego con: comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1; se lo deselecciona, pero no se deshace la acción

Comment: Cuando los cargas haz probado no poner valueMember, es que no estoy en la compu para porbar.